# Need script to change sql server job step properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

currently im using Sql server 2008 r2 (will soon be upgrading to 2014). I need some help in changing job step properties using script.

I have around 20 jobs with each job having 4 steps.

[image]

I'm trying to change the below highlighted option using sql server script. Because manually changing all these options is a difficult task.

[image]

Please help me in writing script to remove the output log path, uncheck append to log, check log to table and check append log to table options.

Answer (score 0):

I got the script

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_id=N'5e998659-8539-45d2-bf4f-874375c0a111', @step_id=1 , 
        @output_file_name=N'', 
        @flags=16`